# Is the product $B D B^T$ always a symmetric tridiagonal matrix? Where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $B$ a sparse matrix.

Tags: matrices, tridiagonal-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices, sparse-matrices

I have a diagonal matrix ${\bf D}_{n \times n}$ and a rectangular matrix ${\bf B}_{m \times n}$ where $n \gg m$.

All but $m$ rows of ${\bf B}$ have non-zero elements. These $m$ rows have only six non-zero elements. (So that ${\bf B}$ has exactly $6m$ non-zero elements.)

I am working on a problem that requires the product ${\bf B D B}^T_{m x m}$ and in all my tests in symbolic algebra software this product is a symmetric tridiagonal matrix. Of course this is not a proof.

Is it possible to show that ${\bf B D B}^T$ is always a symmetric tridiagonal matrix? Or otherwise.

Comment: Your question refers to a matrix $G$ but no information is given about it.

Comment: That's a typo. Fixing it. Thanks

Comment: [note: at my end the G still appears in the question. It now does not appear in the title, but now title and question mismatch.]

Comment: Again, apologies. Its still in the body of the question. Fixing it.

Comment: Did you check whether $BDB^T$ is tridiagonal in the case where $D$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, the property still appears to hold when $D$ is the idenity matrix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150493/discussion-between-olumide-and-coffeemath).